# Load multiple files with Modernizr

Tags: javascript, jquery, modernizr, hammer.js

I am trying to load touch screen specific js files using modernizr.
I am testing Modernizr.touch. If that returns true I want to load 2 files (Hammer.js and FastClick.js) but I am having trouble loading the two files without getting an error. Loading 1 file works fine but when I add 2 it doesnt load the 2nd one. Does anyone know what is wrong here?

here is my code:

```
Modernizr.load([{
    test: Modernizr.touch,
    yep: [
        fastClickUrl,
        hammerUrl
    ],
    callback: function(){
        ...
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return js files for yep. When true, use a callback to initialize the functions.

```
Modernizr.load([{
  test    : Modernizr.touch,
  yep     : ['FastClick.js', 'Hammer.js'],
  callback: function(){
    // yepnope creates a key of the basename resource loaded
    'FastClick.js': function() {
      fastClickURL();
    },
    'Hammer.js': function() {
      hammerURL();
    },
  }
}]);
```